# Firebase how to write security rule for a child that is 2 level random id deep in the tree

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database node called (people) that looks like this:

```
    people
    |
    |
    -------UserID1 //which is a random id
    |       |
    |       |
    |        ----UserId2 //which is a random id
    |            |
    |            |
    |            name:"some_name"
    |            id:"UserId2"
    |            image:"image_url" 
    |
    | 
    |
    -------UserId2
            |
            |
             ----UserId3
                 |
                 |
                 name:"some_name"
                 id:"UserId3"
                 image:"image_url"
```

**If we look at the (people / UserID1 / UserId2) node** :

Since UserId1 and UserId2 are 2 random ids, then if we want to write a rule to UserId2 we will notice that it is 2 random id level deep.

What I want is to write a rule at this specified path that says these:

1) people / UserId1 : can be written by (UserID1) and (UserId2).

2) people / UserId1 : can be read by (UserID1) and (UserId2).

3) people / UserId1 / UserId2 : must end up with a newData that has (name, id, image).

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way Firebase Realtime Database rules [cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authorization) into deeper keys, allowing `people/UserId1` to be writable by `UserId2` is not advised, as this would allow `UserId2` write access to the data of other users stored under `people/UserId1` like `people/UserId1/UserId3`.

But using this trait, we can "add" users that are allowed read & write permissions as we go deeper into the data structure.

So the new conditions are:

- `people/UserId1` - UserId1 has read & write access
- `people/UserId1/UserId2` - UserId2 has read & write access
- `people/UserId1/UserId2` - must always contain 'name', 'id' and 'image' keys
- `people/UserId1/UserId3` - cannot be read/written by UserId2

```js
{
"rules": {
  "people": {
    "$userId1": {
      "$userId2": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $userId2", // add $userId2 to those granted read permission, cascades into deeper keys
        ".write": "auth.uid == $userId2", // add $userId2 to those granted write permission, cascades into deeper keys
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'id', 'image'])" // any new data must have 'name', 'id' and 'image' fields.
      },
      ".read": "auth.uid == $userId1", // add $userId1 to those granted read permission, cascades into deeper keys
      ".write": "auth.uid == $userId1" // add $userId1 to those granted write permission, cascades into deeper keys
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, if it is also required that `people/UserId1/UserId2/id` is equal to `UserId2`, you can change the `".validate"` rule to enforce this:

```js
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'id', 'image']) && newData.child('id').val() == $userId2" // any new data must have 'name', 'id' and 'image' fields and 'id' must have a value of $userId2
```